# sending one file to anther instalation of ubuntu

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I'm new to this networking stuff and would like to know how to get the two installations of Ubuntu talking / find the mac address etc.

I want to know how to send one file that’s on my desktop to the other installation of Ubuntu. Can you advise on how this should be done and point met to documents I should read.

I have them installed on vb.

Answer (score 0):

The most secure and easiest way to do this is Probably SSH.
an SSH-client is installed in Ubuntu by default but you will also need to install the SSH-server.

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

after that you can figure out the IP-address of the machine you want to connect to.

```
ifconfig
```

after that you can use for instance *Filezilla* to connect to the IP-address you found. Choose to connect via *sftp.*